# ul with images doesn't center properly

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` with images that I want to be displayed horizontally centred, inline but it keeps floating a little to the right and gets my window size to be a little over 100% width. Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6trqgj/), you might need to scroll out a little to see it.

Here's the ul:

```
<div class="row graybackground margin-top-60">
  <section id="menuimages" class="margin-top-60">

     <ul class="margin-top-60">
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
           <div class="menubg" style="background-image: url({{ URL::asset('img/training/18911510_m.jpg'); }})">
               <span>{{ link_to('index/#training', 'TRAINING') }}</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
           <div class="menubg" style="background-image: url({{ URL::asset('img/taste/20360155_m.jpg'); }})">
               <span>{{ link_to('index/#eat', 'TASTE') }}</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
           <div class="menubg" style="background-image: url({{ URL::asset('img/relax/14824877_s.jpg'); }})">
                <span>{{ link_to('index/#relax', 'RELAX') }}</span></div>
         </li>
     </ul>

   </section>

</div>
```

**and here the CSS:**

```
.graybackground {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 50px;
}
.margin-top-60 {
    margin-top:60px;
}
.menubg a {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:2px 4px;

}
.menubg a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

No matter where I add margin or padding or whatever, it doesn't move and fit.

I'm using bootstrap 3.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by removing left padding to the **ul** and adding the same rule as @Brian:

```
#menuimages ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.graybackground {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 50px;
    margin:0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8b6trqgj/5/)

Answer (score 2):

The spilling out over 100% of the page is due to the negative margins on `.row` - and this is important to how bootstrap's nested grid works. Wrapping the whole thing in a `.container` will correct this for you (it adds padding to the outside to negate the negative margins).

As for the `ul` being off-center, just do a simple reset on it and its nested `li`s before you start adding:

http://jsfiddle.net/8b6trqgj/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0;
```

to .graybackground

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxxfv2q4/)